# How to make word-space-free words in a div or span so that all words are displayed in div width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to showing some space free words in a width limited `div` or `span`.

[image: The picture of what i have vs what i need]

this is the sample code:

```
.abc {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: blue
}


<div class="abc">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

and i want to show look like this:

http://oi64.tinypic.com/2mnqkco.jpg

thanks

Comment: sorry i search that and dont get any result. maybe dont search properly. next time i search more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="abc">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>  


  .abc{
         width:200px;
          word-wrap: break-word;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

In your box css.

Here's your code with it working:

```html
<style>
    .abc{width: 200px;height: auto;min-height: 100px;background-color: blue; word-wrap: break-word}
</style>
<div class="abc">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this line of CSS should do it for you:

```
.abc {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Or, add this after "background-color: blue"

```
;overflow-wrap: break-word
```